# How to save a Skia4Delphi TSkPaintBox Canvas to file?

Tags: delphi, skia, skia4delphi

I am using the `TSkPaintBox` to capture a freehand signature the same as in the Skia demo app however I can find no way of getting a rasterised version of the canvas out into a `TBitmap`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `MakeScreenshot` function from the `FMX.Controls` unit to take a screenshot of the component and then assign it to a `TBitmap`:

```
var Bitmap := SkPaintBox1.MakeScreenshot;
try

  // Save the Bitmap to file or do whatever you want with it

finally
  Bitmap.Free;
end;
```

The `MakeScreenshot` function returns a `TBitmap`. Just remember to free it when you're done using it.